# How to scroll or prevent scrolling in UICollectionView using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with one section, 10 cells and horizontal scrolling using a Flow Layout.

One cell occupies the entire screen, and has a UITextView and two UIButtons.

How can I prevent scrolling if no button in the cell is selected, and if it is selected, how can I scroll to the next cell on a UIBarButton click?

I would also like to preserve selection in order to be able to go back to the previous cell and change the selection if needed.

Comment: What have you considered and tried? What did it do wrong?

Comment: I have considered writing an if statement in order to enable or disable the scrolling, but don't know if this would be efficient. After this I wanna make a section with 100 cells, and I don't think writing 100 if conditions is right.

Comment: Your data model should hold the selection, and you don't need an if for each cell if you check the data model. Remember the collection is a scroll view so you can disable scrolling.

Comment: You can use this method to scroll over the cells [myCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES]; in the -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath you can made something to store the previous path